# Quality Indicators TFS 2008 report and multiple build types

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, version-control, tfs, reporting-services

In a project we have two build types, one for continuous integration and one that runs our test suite.  When the Quality Indicators report is run, it displays data from all builds regardless of build type.

The report suggests that one can only run it on a specific build type but the query that populates the builds field only seems to work when "All (No Filter)" is passed in as the Build Type parameter.

Is it possible to filter by Build Type so that only builds with tests are run?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done. As an overview:

1. First, create a Report Server project
2. Second, in the project, create a Data Source for the TfsWarehouse OLAP database (again, all Team System activities are ultimately posted to the Data Warehouse, so you’ll always need to use TfsWarehouse), and retrieve any of the reports you want to change
3. Third, make the necessary report changes. Your changes might be data changes, changes to report input parameters, or report layout changes.
4. Finally, publish the report to the Report Server that Team Foundation Server uses when users run the report

... That's pretty high-level - see [PDF: Making Real-Time Decisions with Team System 2008](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/B/5/AB5B5163-4A69-49D9-BCF4-D514CE12BF36/Making_Real-Time_Decisions.pdf) to get the specifics. The PDF talks directly about the report you're asking about.

Hope this helps.